# What is the purpose of the Terminated message

Tags: scala, akka

```
import akka.actor.{ Actor, Props, Terminated }

class WatchActor extends Actor {
  val child = context.actorOf(Props.empty, "child")
  context.watch(child) // <-- this is the only call needed for registration
  var lastSender = context.system.deadLetters

  def receive = {
    case "kill" =>
      context.stop(child); lastSender = sender()
    case Terminated(`child`) => lastSender ! "finished"
  }
}
```

I am getting confused here regarding the `Terminated` message.

When an actor creates a child actor, isn't it by default watching it already?
And if that child actor dies prematurely, the default strategy would be to restart it correct?

What is the purpose of the `Terminated` message in the above code snippet?  (taken from the akka website: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/actors.html)

If the child actor terminates, the `WatchActor` will get that message?  But it is sending the `lastSender()` the "finished" message, and the `lastSender` is the child actor in this case is it not?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose is to get notification from child actor when it dies. 
Talking about example in Akka docs, `lastSender` is the actor that have sent a message to the watchActor:

```
lastSender    ----"kill"--->   watchActor   ---context.stop---> child
              <--"finished--                <--Terminated------
```

So, `lastSender` is an actor that have sent the "kill" message (string) to delegate the killing process. It's not the same as `child`, and not the same as `watchActor`

Another catch is that intermediate WatchActor (kind of "Hitman", not just monitor) might not create a child originally, so that's why it has to subscribe to lifecycle of actor **named** as "child", as you can see from that example:

```
val child = context.actorOf(Props.empty, "child")
context.watch(child)
```

P.S. if you ask me about purpose of such complex protocol, my guess is that it's OOP-like single responsibility. However, IMO, I never liked that akka is distorting original actor's concept (IO-protocol and state handling) with lifecycle stuff. However, this is what you get with Akka - it's kinda simpler with streaming libraries (akka-streams, fs2, monix), so you might try them if it fits your purpose.

Comment: that's true, but I thought if the child actor is created by the watchActor, it doesn't need to explicitly call context.watch.  If it is another actor, then it makes sense to me.

Comment: @coolbreeze yes, akka's approach is kinda "abstruse", I added some small "P.S." about it, but take my opinion with a grain of salt of course :)